# ¿como puedo hacer operar una calculadora básica en netbeans?

Tags: java

espero y me ayuden por favor.
este es el código que tengo pero solo me sale el diseño.

```
import java.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class cal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JPanel panel;
private JButton boton, boton1, boton2, boton3,boton4, boton5, boton6, boton7, boton8, boton9,boton10,botonigual;
private JTextField campoNumero1,campoNumero2,campoSuma;
private JButton botonsuma;
private JButton botonresta;
private JButton botonmultiplicar;
private JButton botondivision;

public static void main(String[]args){

    cal marco= new cal() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    };
    marco.setSize(180,220);
    marco.crearGUI();
    marco.setVisible(true);
}
private void crearGUI(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container ventana= getContentPane ();
    ventana.setLayout(new FlowLayout ());

   panel= new JPanel();
   panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
   panel.setBackground(Color.white);
   ventana.add(panel);

   boton1= new JButton("1");
   ventana.add(boton1);

   boton2=new JButton ("2");
   ventana.add(boton2);
   boton2.addActionListener(this);

   boton3= new JButton ("3");
   ventana.add (boton3);
   boton3.addActionListener(this);

   boton4= new JButton ("4");
   ventana.add (boton4);
   boton4.addActionListener(this);

   boton5= new JButton ("5");
   ventana.add (boton5);
   boton5.addActionListener(this);

   boton6= new JButton ("6");
   ventana.add (boton6);
   boton6.addActionListener(this);

   boton7= new JButton ("7");
   ventana.add (boton7);
   boton7.addActionListener(this);

   boton8= new JButton ("8");
   ventana.add (boton8);
   boton8.addActionListener(this);

   boton9= new JButton ("9");
   ventana.add (boton9);
   boton9.addActionListener(this);

   boton10= new JButton ("0");
   ventana.add (boton10);
   boton10.addActionListener(this);

   botonsuma= new JButton ("+");
   ventana.add (botonsuma);
   botonsuma.addActionListener(this);

   botonresta= new JButton ("-");
   ventana.add (botonresta);
   botonresta.addActionListener(this);

   botonmultiplicar= new JButton ("*");
   ventana.add (botonmultiplicar);
   botonmultiplicar.addActionListener(this);

   botondivision= new JButton ("/");
   ventana.add (botondivision);
   botondivision.addActionListener(this);

   botonigual=new JButton("=");
   ventana.add(botonigual);
   botonigual.addActionListener(this); 
 }
```

Comment: Da más información. Te faltan dos líneas por incluir en el código los "import". ¿Usas Java Swing? ¿Tienes las librerías añadidas? Muestra una captura de pantalla del error que te da.

Comment: gracias  omaza1990.
si utilizo "java swing" y si coloco librerias.

Comment: y hasta hay me genera lo que es el diseño de la calculadora pero no puedo operar en ella

Answer (score 1):

Ya casi lo tienes, sólo te falta agregar código al `actionPerformed` y algunos detalles, aquí tu código modificado y funcionando (no es calculadora, sólo imprime el valor correspondiente al botón)

```
import java.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class cal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel panel;
    public JButton boton, boton1, boton2, boton3,boton4, boton5, boton6, boton7, boton8, boton9,boton10,botonigual;
    private JTextField campoNumero1,campoNumero2,campoSuma;
    public JButton botonsuma;
    public JButton botonresta;
    public JButton botonmultiplicar;
    public JButton botondivision;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        cal marco= new cal() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == this.boton1)
                    System.out.println(1);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton2)
                    System.out.println(2);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton3)
                    System.out.println(3);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton4)
                    System.out.println(4);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton5)
                    System.out.println(5);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton6)
                    System.out.println(6);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton7)
                    System.out.println(7);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton8)
                    System.out.println(8);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton9)
                    System.out.println(9);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.boton10)
                    System.out.println(10);
                else if (e.getSource() == this.botonsuma)
                    System.out.println("+");
                else if (e.getSource() == this.botonresta)
                    System.out.println("-");
                else if (e.getSource() == this.botonmultiplicar)
                    System.out.println("*");
                else if (e.getSource() == this.botondivision)
                    System.out.println("/");
                else
                    System.out.println("=");
            }
        };
        marco.setSize(180,220);
        marco.crearGUI();
        marco.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void crearGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container ventana= getContentPane();
        ventana.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        ventana.add(panel);

        boton1= new JButton("1");
        ventana.add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);

        boton2=new JButton ("2");
        ventana.add(boton2);
        boton2.addActionListener(this);

        boton3= new JButton ("3");
        ventana.add (boton3);
        boton3.addActionListener(this);

        boton4= new JButton ("4");
        ventana.add (boton4);
        boton4.addActionListener(this);

        boton5= new JButton ("5");
        ventana.add (boton5);
        boton5.addActionListener(this);

        boton6= new JButton ("6");
        ventana.add (boton6);
        boton6.addActionListener(this);

        boton7= new JButton ("7");
        ventana.add (boton7);
        boton7.addActionListener(this);

        boton8= new JButton ("8");
        ventana.add (boton8);
        boton8.addActionListener(this);

        boton9= new JButton ("9");
        ventana.add (boton9);
        boton9.addActionListener(this);

        boton10= new JButton ("0");
        ventana.add (boton10);
        boton10.addActionListener(this);

        botonsuma= new JButton ("+");
        ventana.add (botonsuma);
        botonsuma.addActionListener(this);

        botonresta= new JButton ("-");
        ventana.add (botonresta);
        botonresta.addActionListener(this);

        botonmultiplicar= new JButton ("*");
        ventana.add (botonmultiplicar);
        botonmultiplicar.addActionListener(this);

        botondivision= new JButton ("/");
        ventana.add (botondivision);
        botondivision.addActionListener(this);

        botonigual=new JButton("=");
        ventana.add(botonigual);
        botonigual.addActionListener(this); 
    }
}
```

Ahí está, como puedes ver tiene algunas modificaciones como `e.getSource()` que devuelve una referencia al botón que originó el evento y lo compara con `this.boton` y los botones son públicos esto es para que puedan hacer referencia correctamente a los mismos, pues eso se está sobreescribiendo desde un método *estático* (`main`).

Sin embargo, no es la única forma de hacerlo, acá te presento otras dos:

**Sobreescribiendo el método actionPerformed afuera del main**

```
import java.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class cal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton boton, boton1, boton2, boton3,boton4, boton5, boton6, boton7, boton8, boton9,boton10,botonigual;
    private JTextField campoNumero1,campoNumero2,campoSuma;
    private JButton botonsuma;
    private JButton botonresta;
    private JButton botonmultiplicar;
    private JButton botondivision;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        cal marco= new cal();
        marco.setSize(180,220);
        marco.crearGUI();
        marco.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void crearGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container ventana= getContentPane();
        ventana.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        ventana.add(panel);

        boton1= new JButton("1");
        ventana.add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);

        boton2=new JButton ("2");
        ventana.add(boton2);
        boton2.addActionListener(this);

        boton3= new JButton ("3");
        ventana.add (boton3);
        boton3.addActionListener(this);

        boton4= new JButton ("4");
        ventana.add (boton4);
        boton4.addActionListener(this);

        boton5= new JButton ("5");
        ventana.add (boton5);
        boton5.addActionListener(this);

        boton6= new JButton ("6");
        ventana.add (boton6);
        boton6.addActionListener(this);

        boton7= new JButton ("7");
        ventana.add (boton7);
        boton7.addActionListener(this);

        boton8= new JButton ("8");
        ventana.add (boton8);
        boton8.addActionListener(this);

        boton9= new JButton ("9");
        ventana.add (boton9);
        boton9.addActionListener(this);

        boton10= new JButton ("0");
        ventana.add (boton10);
        boton10.addActionListener(this);

        botonsuma= new JButton ("+");
        ventana.add (botonsuma);
        botonsuma.addActionListener(this);

        botonresta= new JButton ("-");
        ventana.add (botonresta);
        botonresta.addActionListener(this);

        botonmultiplicar= new JButton ("*");
        ventana.add (botonmultiplicar);
        botonmultiplicar.addActionListener(this);

        botondivision= new JButton ("/");
        ventana.add (botondivision);
        botondivision.addActionListener(this);

        botonigual=new JButton("=");
        ventana.add(botonigual);
        botonigual.addActionListener(this); 
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == boton1)
            System.out.println("1");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton2)
            System.out.println("2");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton3)
            System.out.println("3");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton4)
            System.out.println("4");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton5)
            System.out.println("5");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton6)
            System.out.println("6");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton7)
            System.out.println("7");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton8)
            System.out.println("8");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton9)
            System.out.println("9");
        else if (e.getSource() == boton10)
            System.out.println("10");
        else if (e.getSource() == botonsuma)
            System.out.println("+");
        else if (e.getSource() == botonresta)
            System.out.println("-");
        else if (e.getSource() == botonmultiplicar)
            System.out.println("*");
        else if (e.getSource() == botondivision)
            System.out.println("/");
        else
            System.out.println("=");
    }
}
```

Dará el mismo resultado, pero como ves los `JButton` ahora son privados, y no está el `this.boton`, sino solamente el botón correspondiente.

**Añadiendo a cada botón un ActionListener diferente**

```
import java.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class cal extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel;
    public JButton boton, boton1, boton2, boton3,boton4, boton5, boton6, boton7, boton8, boton9,boton10,botonigual;
    private JTextField campoNumero1,campoNumero2,campoSuma;
    public JButton botonsuma;
    public JButton botonresta;
    public JButton botonmultiplicar;
    public JButton botondivision;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        cal marco= new cal();
        marco.setSize(180,220);
        marco.crearGUI();
        marco.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void crearGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container ventana= getContentPane();
        ventana.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        ventana.add(panel);

        boton1= new JButton("1");
        ventana.add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println(1);
            }
        });

        boton2=new JButton ("2");
        ventana.add(boton2);
        //lo mismo pero usando lambda
        boton2.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println(2);
        });

        boton3= new JButton ("3");
        ventana.add (boton3);
        boton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println(3);
            }
        });

        boton4= new JButton ("4");
        ventana.add (boton4);
        boton4.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println(4);
        });

        boton5= new JButton ("5");
        ventana.add (boton5);
        boton5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println(5);
            }
        });

        boton6= new JButton ("6");
        ventana.add (boton6);
        boton6.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println(6);
        });

        boton7= new JButton ("7");
        ventana.add (boton7);
        boton7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println(7);
            }
        });

        boton8= new JButton ("8");
        ventana.add (boton8);
        boton8.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println(8);
        });

        boton9= new JButton ("9");
        ventana.add (boton9);
        boton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println(9);
            }
        });

        boton10= new JButton ("0");
        ventana.add (boton10);
        boton10.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println(0);
        });

        botonsuma= new JButton ("+");
        ventana.add (botonsuma);
        botonsuma.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println("+");
            }
        });

        botonresta= new JButton ("-");
        ventana.add (botonresta);
        botonresta.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("-");
        });

        botonmultiplicar= new JButton ("*");
        ventana.add (botonmultiplicar);
        botonmultiplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println("*");
            }
        });

        botondivision= new JButton ("/");
        ventana.add (botondivision);
        botondivision.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("/");
        });

        botonigual=new JButton("=");
        ventana.add(botonigual);
        botonigual.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.out.println("=");
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Como puedes notar ahora cada `addActionListener` ya no recibe `this` como parámetro, sino un *ActionListener* con el método `actionPerfomed` sobreescrito, o una función lambda que es más corto el código, intercalé ambos para notar que realmente tienen el mismo resultado.

Con esto, solamente falta que en lugar de imprimir el valor se realicen operaciones con él, pero te lo dejo a ti, ya que no se trata de hacer todo el trabajo. Espero haberte ayudado.